# How to convert ibm character types bytes to string in Dart?

Tags: string, dart, byte, data-conversion

I have some data (probably ISO8859 Family...) comes through IBM server (converted from IBM to Oracle) as shown below. I need to convert this bytes to string. But cannot print a full string. Just şhows some garbage character.

```
  List<int> bytesIBM = [135, 128, 167, 166, 141, 152, 159, 158, 148, 153, 129, 154];
  String s = new String.fromCharCodes(bytesIBM);
  print("_ibm: $s");
  print("-------------------------------");
```

**And output:**
_ibm: ÂÂÂ§Â¦ÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂ

How to convert ibm character types bytes to string in Dart?

**Update:**

If I use this I get an error:

```
 List<int> bytesIBM = [135, 128, 167, 166, 141, 152, 159, 158, 148, 153, 129, 154];
  String s = utf8.decode(bytesIBM);
  print("_ibm: $s");
  print("-------------------------------");
```

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x87 (at offset 0)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:568:13)
#1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:344:13)
#2      Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:66:60)
#3      main (file:///home/capital/IdeaProjects/untitled/bin/main.dart:47:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)

Process finished with exit code 255
```